# How can I connect my laptop the the LAN connection of the desktop computer

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, connection, lan

My computer technician has formatted my computer last week and created a LAN connection.
I have got a wireless router [Kraun] ....now, I have always been able to connect to this connection with my laptop.
Merely, I would always go to `192.168.1.1` and follow the wizard in order to create a wireless connection so that in the Network center of my laptop, I was able to find the name of the connection, insert the password only once and then connect automatically.
Now I can't anymore!!

The desktop computer is Windows XP Professional.
My laptop is Windows 7 Ultimate.

Here the LAN connection of the desktop computer at the bottom of the task bar ....

[image]

[image]

Now ...it is quite strange because on my laptop, I have always been able to connect to this connection. In the Network panel, the connection was called "ALICE WIFI".
Here's the 'ALICE WIFI' connection

[image]

Whn I try to connect, it asks me obviously the password but i cant remember it.
I tried to reset my router to follow again the wizard but the router lights soon or later appear again also the internet central light which shouldn't appear].

Help me!!
:(

If you don't understand and wanted more details, write it to me and i iwll let u know!
Thank you, quite a lot!

~Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting one or the other computer to the router with a cable, access the router configuration page (192.168.1.1) and look for the wireless security page.  You should be able to see the necessary information there.  If you have forgotten the username/password combo for the router, try using the factory defaults found in your user guide.  If that doesn't work, you may need to reset the router to factory defaults and re-configuring it.  Good luck.